# Application name displayed in URL on load and reload after deploying - InertiaJS Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I've converted an app using Laravel with Inertia and Vue.js, In local it's working fine but when I deployed on server while accessing `login` page it's url changes to `https://mywebsite.com/module/login` and when I refresh or visit this changed link it appears `404 error`.

I've checked `ziggy routes`, `web.php` and also regenerated `ziggy routes` again by changing application url to live for production purspose but still same.

Is there's any deployment configuration with InertiaJS? I've checked but haven't found that type of config.